# Advice regarding preliminary proof of an untrue theorem

Tags: proof-writing

I am writing about objects A and B.  They rely on well-known object C.  I have defined A and B to be equal but I can use C to show that they are not equal.  My intention is to show that C cannot be as commonly defined.  Here is my question:

Is it allowed in the math grammar to use a theorem to deliberately prove something that is untrue?  I have one theorem that shows A(C)=1 and I can make another that shows B(C)=5.  This is wrong because A(C)=B(C).  Therefore, it feels wrong to make a theorem that proves B(C)=5.  My intention is to derive the result B(C)=5 so that later I can show that there is a problem with C.  What technique can I use to show something provisionally with the intention to show that actually it is wrong?  I feel like it would be ugly to use a theorem to "prove" something and then say, "Haha, actually that theorem was a lie!!!"  How is this sort of thing done?  THANKS

Comment: Have you heard of [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction)

Comment: I have but I am not sure how I would use it here.  What theorem would I prove?  If I used proof by contradiction then the theorem would need to be like, "The properties of C are not as commonly expected," but that seems too non-specific.

Comment: If $C$ implies a false statement, that implies $C$ is false.